# linux code jumper says bad option "bind": .window.listbox bind "<Double-1>" {openEditor}"

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Basically what this program is suppose to do is make it quick and easy to find each subroutine in a perl script by listing each perl subroutine in a TCL/TK listbox.  When the user clicks on the listbox item it will open that specific linenumber up of the perl program in the editor window using the shell command "nedit-client +linenumber  perl_file".

Here's my problem:

**Here's my TCL/TK error:**

```
bad option "bind": must be activate, bbox, 
cget, configure, curselection, delete, 
get, index, insert, itemcget, 
itemconfigure, nearest, scan, see, selection, size, xview, or yview
    while executing
".window.listbox bind "<Double-1>" {openEditor}"
    (file "./jumper" line 80)
```

**Here's my TCL/TK code:**

```
#!/bin/tclsh

package require Tk

# Create a new Tcl interpreter
interp create gui

# Define a callback function to populate the listbox
proc populateListbox {} {
    # Open the Perl file for reading
    set fileHandle [open "my_perl_script_with_subroutines.pl" r]

    # Initialize an empty dictionary to store subroutine positions and names
    set subroutineData {}

    # Read the Perl file line by line
    while {[gets $fileHandle line] != -1} {
        # Check if the line contains a subroutine declaration
        if {[regexp {^\s*sub\s+(\w+)} $line -> subroutineName]} {
            # Get the current line number
            set lineNumber [tell $fileHandle]

            # Store the subroutine data in the dictionary
            dict set subroutineData $subroutineName $lineNumber
        }
    }

    # Close the file
    close $fileHandle

    # Sort the dictionary by subroutine name
    set sortedSubroutineData [lsort [dict keys $subroutineData]]

    # Clear the listbox
    $listbox delete 0 end

    # Populate the listbox with sorted subroutine names
    foreach subroutineName $sortedSubroutineData {
        $listbox insert end $subroutineName
    }
}

# Define a callback function for double-click event on listbox
proc openEditor {widget} {
    # Get the selected item in the listbox
    set selection [$widget get [$widget curselection]]

    # Get the line number and file name from the subroutine data
    set subroutineData [dict get $subroutineData $selection]
    set lineNumber [dict get $subroutineData lineNumber]
    set fileName "example.pl"

    # Launch the editor with the line number and file name
    set cmd "nedit-client +$lineNumber $fileName"
    exec $cmd
}


# Create a new Tk window
toplevel .window
wm title .window "Perl Subroutines"

# Create a listbox widget
listbox .window.listbox -width 40 -height 20
pack .window.listbox -fill both -expand 1

# Create a "Refresh" button to populate the listbox
button .window.button -text "Refresh" -command populateListbox
pack .window.button

# Create a scrollbar for the listbox
scrollbar .window.scrollbar -orient vertical -command ".window.listbox yview"
pack .window.scrollbar -side right -fill y
.window.listbox configure -yscrollcommand ".window.scrollbar set"

# Configure the listbox to select mode and bind double-click event
.window.listbox configure -selectmode single
.window.listbox bind "<Double-1>" {openEditor}

# Call the populateListbox function to initially populate the listbox
populateListbox

# Start the Tk event loop
tkwait window .window
```

**example of my_perl_script_with_subroutines.pl:**

```perl
sub gen_report {


}

sub tagutil_linkwork($) {


}

#------------------------------------------------------------
sub tagutil_getfiles($) {

}


sub tagutil_meld(\@\@) {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
.window.listbox bind "<Double-1>" {openEditor}
```

doesn't work; it's *not* usually a method of widgets because widgets aren't the only bindable things (and that's not going to change because where there is a `bind` method, such as on a `canvas` or a `text`, it applies to things within the widget). As such, you should instead write:

```
bind .window.listbox <Double-1> {openEditor}
```

Yes, it's just swapping two words around.

---

Re:

> widgets aren't the only bindable things

You can also bind to widget classes (Tk does that internally for the most part), or the global `all` token (rarely useful FWIW) or even to custom binding tags. It's not very common for user code to do those, but the capability is absolutely invaluable when you need it. Things work the way they do because that's how they *must* work for advanced usage.